# Javascript: Regex to get specific part of the URI

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a single line of javascript that would return the bold part of URIs highlighted below from window.location.pathname?

- /**Arena**/
- /en/**Arena**/ (ignores two letter language codes - not a set list)
- /pt-br/**Arena**/ (ignores four letter lang codes with hyphen - not a set list)
- /en/**Arena**/Room/ (ignores further parts of URL)

For bonus points, in the case that the URI is **/**, I would like it to return *Home*

I would like to use this in a tag manager that accepts only a single line of code as a return function, hence the need for a single line function.

Similarly, is there an additional regex expression that could also return the language codes parts of the above URIs: *en*, *pt-br* or any other languages codes that match either of those two patterns, and that defaults to returning *en* if otherwise not present?

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: RegExp that's used as a matching language can't match non existant parts. It can't "return default".

Comment: Can `Arena` part start with a lower case letter? Can it be 2 characters long? Can `language` part start with an upper case letter?

Comment: `var arr = path.split("/"); return (arr.length < 5) ? arr[arr.length-2] : arr[2];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use non-capturing/optional regex groups to look for the language codes. Capture the first set of non-`/` characters. If no match, set to default `Home` value.

```
var regex = /^\/(?:[a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?\/)?([^/]+)/,
    matches = window.location.pathname.match(regex);

var page = matches ? matches[1] : 'Home';
console.log(page); // Arena
```

---

Similarly, you can chose to capture the language portion:

```
var regex = /^\/(?:([a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?)\/)?([^/]+)/,
    matches = window.location.pathname.match(regex);

var language = matches ? matches[1] : 'en',
    page = matches ? matches[2] : 'Home';
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lE4xQ3/3)**